# Proving $f(x)>0$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$ given that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x)>f(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable, with the properties

(1)  $\ f(0)=0$, and

(2) $\ f'(x)>f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}.$

Prove that $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^+.$

It's clear that one can get that $f$ is positive on some interval, by utilizing the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of the derivative (using $\epsilon=f'(0)/2>f(0)/2=0$) for all positive $x$ in some $\delta$-neighborhood centered at $0$. How would one get this over all positive reals? I've tried to proceed by contradiction, but that hasn't yielded much for me thus far, using things like the mean value or creating auxiliary functions. Maybe someone with a bit more wit could direct me down the right path?

Comment: I think the condition $f\neq0$ is necessary or $f'>f$!

Comment: I've edited the body. I'm assuming you meant $>$ rather than $\geq$.

Comment: Typo. Should've been strict.

Comment: Thanks. Beat me by 10 seconds!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set $g(x) = e^{-x}f(x)$. One then has $g(0) = 0$ and $g'(x) = -e^{-x}f(x) + e^{-x}f'(x) = e^{-x}(f'(x)-f(x)) > 0$ for all $x$.

Thus, $g(x) > g(0)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$, or $f(x) > 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Very nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(x)>f(x)\Longleftrightarrow e^{-x}(f'(x)-f(x))>0\Longleftrightarrow \frac{d}{dx}(e^{-x}f(x))>0 $$
$$\Longleftrightarrow 0\le\int_0^x\frac{d}{dt}(e^{-t}f(t)) dt  =e^{-x}f(x)- f(0) =e^{-x}f(x) $$
that is $$ e^{-x}f(x)\ge 0\Longleftrightarrow f(x)\ge 0$$

But $f'(x)>f(x)\ge0$ which implies that $f'(x)>0$ which means $f$ is strictly increasing 
Therfore,
$$ 0<x\implies 0=f(0)<f(x)$$

That is $f(x)>0$ on $(0,\infty)$